# Why does flashing a BBB eMMC take so long from SD card, and how can I monitor the progress?

Tags: linux, sd-card

As you may know, flashing the BeagleBone Black eMMC with a new Linux Image from the SD card takes quite a long time - up to 45 minutes.

Is there a reason why, and is there a way to monitor the progress to make sure it is not stalled out?

Writing the image to the SD card took less than 5 minutes on my PC, and my understanding was that eMMC memory is several times faster than SD memory.  Why does it take so long then?

Answer (score 0):

From [ShallowSky blog](http://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/flashing-beaglebone-black.html),

> Over an hour? Why so long?
>
> I wondered that, of course, so in my second attempt at flashing, once I had the serial cable plugged in, I ran ps periodically to see what it was doing.
>
> And for nearly half that time -- over 25 minutes -- what it was doing was configuring Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You know that copying is a "process", and the time it takes to copy a file depends on many factors, one of them you have already mentioned. "eMMC memory is several times faster than SD memory".

But you must remember that the processor in your  PC is several times faster than the ARM Cortex in your BBB. Therefore, expect the copying to take longer when flashing.

I hope this was clear.

Regards,